# System.InvalidOperationException: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase

Tags: acumatica

Version 19.108

I'm getting this error when trying to install two customization projects.  One project is extending a custom page in the other project.  There are a few DLL's in play that are being referenced to call web API's.  When I Google this error, I get hits for modifying the web.config but, I'm trying to install this in the cloud - acumatica.com

[image]

I've tried building all DLLs in x64 but, no dice.

I've got no problems on my local machine.  This is only happening on a cloud install.

Any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: How reproducible is it? Can you try RESTART APPLICATION from page APPLY UPDATES?

Comment: Do you own all sources? Try to remove code to narrow the issue scope.

Comment: Also try publishing them one after the other (two publish phase) with proper Level set in customization page.

Comment: Yeah, the levels and installing one at a time didn't seem to work.  It looks like one of the other customization projects was causing the issue.  Fortunately, we're able to exclude that one.  I had some screen extensions and BLC extensions in it but, they were not compiled into a DLL.  Not sure why it caused an issue...

Comment: I ran into the same problem with a project that uses a third-party library and I ended up disabling the compatibility check through web.config

Comment: If runtime code is an issue (no DLL) I would expect all runtime code to be incompatible because they are compiled in a single RuntimCode_GUID.dll. Maybe you removed all runtime code as a workaround, that might just obscure the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for all of the info!  I agree - removing the runtime code seems to just side-step the issue.  So, I'm thinking there's an incompatibility between my built DLLs and the run time DLL.  I head in that direction.  My DLLs are built with Any CPU.  I can't modify the web.config since this is on a cloud server.

Comment: I apologize.  I just noticed that there is a DLL project at the bottom of my solution in Visual Studio.  It is set to x64.  That was causing the issue.  Hugues gets the win on this one.  Thanks again, fellers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be mixing code that targets different platform (Mixed Platforms). Publishing one customization after the other can help (try both order). When publishing both at the same time it's possible that Any CPU chooses a default platform which isn't compatible with an assembly in the other customization.

Ideally all assemblies (DLL) included in the Files section of your customization project should target the same platform. It is preferred to choose Any CPU platform. Otherwise having only 64 bit assembly could work. If using third party libraries make sure you included the Any CPU version (preferred) or 64 bit version but not the 32 bit version.

You can change platform in the Configuration Manager in Visual Studio:

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019